# How to create Google Maps like Toolbar with DrawerButton, SearchView and Translucent status bar so that Map can be seen behind the status bar?

Tags: android

[image]

I want to get toolbar like this image.
Also, consider the map which is getting displayed beneath the translucent status bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out how to achieve that kind of toolbar.

**Here is my `activity_maps.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                    app:cardElevation="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                            app:title="Title"
                            android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient"
                            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </FrameLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_drawer"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer_drawer"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**`style.xml`:**

```
<style name="MapsTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
</style>
```

> Output:
>
> [image]

Comment: the latest version of the Google Map app doesn't use `android:windowTranslucentStatus`, it's fully transparent now

Answer (score 0):

For the status bar do this, you call ths in your on create and pass in the color of your status bar

```
private void changeStatusBarColor(String color){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    }
}
```

For the tool bar you would have to create a custom tool bar style with i think a card view background and replace the default tool bar with the one you have designed

Comment: your code is changing just the status bar color. But the Toolbar is getting behind the status bar. Can you provide the code if you can achieve the same toolbar as in the photo in the question? It will be very helpful.